# Update existing List object in a Dictionary?

Tags: list, dictionary

We have an issue representing file data in a .NET Dictionary collection which might be easier to explain with a simplified example:

```
Dictionary<int, string> header = new Dictionary<int, string>();
Dictionary<int, List<string>> lines = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
List<string> line;

//Create first header/lines Dic objects
header.Add(1, "Bill");
line = new List<string>();
line.Add("G");
line.Add("A");
line.Add("T");
line.Add("E");
lines.Add(1, line);

//Create second header/lines Dic objects
header.Add(2, "Steven");
line = new List<string>();
line.Add("B");
line.Add("A");
line.Add("L");
line.Add("L");
line.Add("M");
line.Add("E");
line.Add("R");
lines.Add(2, line);

//Update first lines Dic object by adding a final line
line = new List<string>();
line.Add("S");
???
```

It's at this point I'm not sure how I can add the new string to the end of the first List object in the Dictionary so that it contains the characters "G", "A", "T", "E", "S".  Is there a way to update an existing Dictionary object when the value parameter is a List object?

Answer (score 0):

In your lines dictionary, you can access the list with key 1, like so...

```
line = lines[1]; 
line.Add("S");
```

Suppose you wanted to put an S on the end of BALLMER, then it's the other key, 2, like so...

```
line = lines[2]; 
line.Add("S");
```

Just to see the data, I iterate over each list in your dictionary like this...

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> entry in lines) {
    foreach (string s in entry.Value) {
        Console.Write(s);
    }
}
```

Finally, I don't recommend this necessarily but if your implementation requires, you may use the AddRange function to append one list to another, like this...

```
line = new List<string>();
line.Add("S");
lines[1].AddRange(line); //combines two list objects, one after the other
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what we were looking for.